# testing react component, mocking props

Tags: reactjs

Folks,
  Front-end newb here.   Trying to understand how to properly pass mock `props` to a constructor of a component....

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        let dataToDecode = QueryString.parse(props.location.search).data;
        const data = QueryString.parse(Base64.decode(dataToDecode));
        this.state = {
            email: data.email,
            ...
        };
    ...
```

So how does one mock the `props` in react?   can `testing-library/react` or `jest` help with this?

i.e. the tests need to cover proper uri and an incorrect one.
`https://domain/path?data=somebase64encodedstring`

```
it('renders without crashing', () => {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, div);
});
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to make use of the [Enzyme](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/) library, which allows you to shallow render or fully render your component. Enzyme allows you to easily test your component's output.

In this scenario, it will be sufficient to use [shallow rendering](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html).

This is one way you can shallow render your components with your mocked props.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

describe('<MyComponent />', () => {

  it('sample test', () => {
    const myComponent = <MyComponent 
      location={mockLocation} 
      otherProps={otherMockProps}
    />
    const wrapper = shallow(myComponent);
    // expect().....
  });

})
```

As you can see from the above, we called the shallow rendering API, `shallow()`, on your component together with the required props. From there onwards, you can carry out other forms of behaviour, such as calling of methods, or spying on method calls, and test for the desired behaviour.